# How to save extra info during user signup process using firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building a website where I've integrated [firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) for login/signup of site users.

Users can login/signup via either email-password or mobile OTP method.
I'm using official firebase js Auth UI Widget: [firebaseui-web](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) for this authentication process.

While signup, I also want to capture additional user details like full name, gender, age etc.

I found 2 approaches on the web for this:

1. Store extra info in firestore after successful signup.

   Issue with this approach is I want to be it an **atomic transaction**. Means, either all the extra info should be stored during signup process **or** signup process shouldn't succeed. I'm not sure how to implement this flow or is it even possible at all.
2. Store extra info in firebase [auth object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) field like in displayName, photoURL using JSON.stringify/JSON.parse method. I'm using their auth UI widget and not sure how to embed this info during email or mobile OTP signup.

So, how to save extra info of user during signup process? **Any different approach maybe?**

Website is hosted on firebase hosting. Site uses firestore for storing any additional data of users because firebase auth doesn't provide this functionality. I've also implemented firebase cloud functions (Typescript, node.js) for some basic CRUD operations. So in nutshell, a full firebase environment.

Comment: @downvoter, it's a valid SO question. why did you downvote without giving any context?

Answer (score 8):

This is something that every firebase user has to deal with. How is generally solved? As other users point out, it is solved by adding the extra user information into Firestore. Can you guarantee that atomiticy? No, you can't, auth and db are two different systems, you can add the user to auth and in the callback find out you cannot add the user to db because you dont have internet connection for instance. What people do? Generally live with it.

If it is fundamental for your application to guarantee atomiticy you can go an extra mile and implement your authentication in a firebase function. For instance, this is an example of a two step sign in:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export async function create(req: Request, res: Response) {
   try {
       const { displayName, password, email, role } = req.body

       if (!displayName || !password || !email || !role) {
           return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Missing fields' })
       }

       const { uid } = await admin.auth().createUser({
           displayName,
           password,
           email
       })
       await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { role })

       return res.status(201).send({ uid })
   } catch (err) {
       return handleError(res, err)
   }
}

function handleError(res: Response, err: any) {
   return res.status(500).send({ message: `${err.code} - ${err.message}` });
}
```

You could add the user removal from auth if something goes wrong. This guarantees at least that your rollback code will be executed in the Google servers.

This code example was extracted from https://www.toptal.com/firebase/role-based-firebase-authentication

Comment: I am not sure how secure this approach is as the creds are sent over the server without encryption. And whether it's an actual approach which people use it in prod server.

Comment: but i must say this is one heck of a way to implement artificial atomicity.

Comment: Regarding encryption, the protocol used by Firebase is https, it is encrypted on the transport layer  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable. Actually as far as I know, all interactions with Firebase are secure. A different discussion would be the encryption on client or server side, but this is something that doesn't apply for sign up

Answer (score 2):

The additional information you want to capture would indeed usually be stored in an additional database, such as Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database. Custom claims are typically reserved for information related to access control, such as group membership and whether the user is an admin.

There is no atomic way to add additional information during sign-up beyond the minimal information that is needed for the sign-up (i.e. the email address and password when using email+password authentication). If atomicity is a requirement for your use-case, you may want to look beyond Firebase.

Comment: so manually adding info during email signup to firebase auth object property like in photoURL is also not possible? how about custom claims, can i store data in this during signup?

Comment: You can set a URL in the `photoURL` property, but it won't be atomic upon account creation. And you shouldn't store that type of information in custom claims, as they're: 1) limited to 1000 bytes in size, 2) sent with every request.

Comment: I don't get it. if i can set the url in photoURL as you mentioned then it should be saved along with other auth fields during signup, right?

Comment: You need a `User` object to set the photo URL. By that time the account has been created, so it's not atomic. And since you said "I want to be it an atomic transaction" in your question, that'd make it a no go. If you give up on atomicity, then you can set any properties that exist in the user object: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to save a user's data. I assume you are saving the data to be able to do some operations on it later. Thus it is advisable you should save your data in cloud firestore. Cloud Firestore's queries will help you in the future to be able to manipulate any CRUD operations that you may want on the data.

A good way of storing the data is after registering the user with firebase auth. You can take the userID returned by firebase auth in the oncomplete listener, then take make a document with its key being the userID inside your USERS collection,then you save the extra information about the user in that document.

Comment: i know i can store/ask the information later after signup but, i'm looking to save the extra info upfront.. like when you signup for gmail

Comment: i agree it does not matter if you're using firestore, but the userID can be used with any data source you're wanting to use. so like any other storage the given `userID` is your key for the user.

Answer (score 0):

First signup and `onComplete`method check if signup is successful.

```
     if (task.isSuccessful()) { 
   // String userId = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
   //  get user unique id 
   // saveUserData()
    }
```

get user unique id and use it as key and store data like

```
applicationName->usersNode->userId->data
```

check if data is stored successfully proceed to next activity or Home page else remove user from auth and ask him to retry again.