# How to store custom user detail during signing into firebase web app

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using angular for the firebase web app. I'm want to build an (emailpasswordauthentication ) that can save additional data during a signing, I didn't find any solution on the web.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a good idea to search SO before asking questions as it may have already been asked. In this case, it's been asked a lot and here are some results on [storing additional user info](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5Dstore+additional+user+info) and there's a great answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138068/how-to-save-extra-info-during-user-signup-process-using-firebase-authentication) that goes in depth.

Comment: no, but the question was different. I want to save additional data "during" signing. They were showing how to update data

Comment: *during signing* is very unclear... when is *during* and what does *signing* mean? When posting questions you have to give us enough information to clearly understand what you're trying to do. When we have incomplete data, we could spent a LOT of time tossing answers out that are not even close.